# React native : trying to hide search bar on scroll

Tags: css, react-native

i am currently trying to hide my search bar when scrolling.

The components i have on screen are a search bar at the top followed by a horizontal scroll view with tabs, then my flatlist.

with the current implementation, when i load the screen, the search bar is covering the tabs and when i scroll down the search bar hides and the tabs appear.

What i am trying to do is, when i load the screen the search bar, tabs and flatlist should all be visible then when i start scrolling the search bar hides and the tabs and flatlist fill the available space at the top.

Also, another problem i am encountering is when i keep scrolling up the search bar keeps moving up until it disappears.

here is my code:

```
const scrollY = new Animated.Value(0)
const diffClamp=Animated.diffClamp(scrollY,0,100)
const translateY = diffClamp.interpolate({
inputRange:[0,100],
outputRange:[0,-100]
})

return(

<Animated.View style={{transform: 
    [{translateY:translateY}],elevation:4,zIndex:100}}>
    <SearchBar 
     containerStyle={{height:40,marginBottom:20,position:"absolute",
     left:0,right:0,top:0}} 
    inputContainerStyle={{height:40}}
    />
    </Animated.View>

    <View style={{paddingHorizontal:6}}>
    <ScrollView 
    horizontal 
    style={{
    marginBottom:10,
    height:30,
    }} 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
    {categories.map(e=>(
            <TouchableOpacity 
            style={[
                {paddingHorizontal:10,paddingBottom:0},
                label===e.label && 
                {
                borderRadius:2,
                marginBottom:-20,
            }
                ]} 
                onPress={()=>}
                >
            <AppText>{e.label}</AppText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <FlatList
      data={posts} // to have all the data
      keyExtractor={(post) => post.id.toString()}
      renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
       <Card
          title={item.title}
          subTitle={item.subTitle}
        />
      )}
      onScroll={(e)=>{
          scrollY.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)
      }}
    />
)
```

with position:"absolute", the search bar is on top on the tabs so instead of position:"absolute" i tried "relative", when i scroll down the search bar hides but there is blank space above the tabs.

I am also using the react native elements search bar component.

would appreciate any help possible, thank you in advance.

*UPDATE*

After following J.Doe solution, which is the correct solution to solving the translation problem, i now faced a new problem correlating to this.

Since i can toggle between the different tabs in my scrollView, each tab has its corresponding Flatlist data. If the FlatList has more than 3 data items the functionality works correct, but if it has 1 or 2 data items then the translation functionality stops working.

if i am on tab 1 (with many data items) and scroll down (ie. search bar is translated) then tap on tab 2 that only contains 1 data item, i am not able to scroll the screen to see the search bar.

Here is my code:

```
const categories = [
{
  label: "Sports",
  id: 1,
},
{
  label: "News",
  id: 2,
},
{
  label: "Food",
  id: 3,
},
]

const[label,setLabel]=useState(categories[0]?.label)

const [currentCategoryId, setCurrentCategoryId] = useState(1)

const setLabelFilter=label=>{
setLabel(label)
}

const toggleBrands = (categoryId) => {
setCurrentCategoryId(categoryId)
};
```

Here is my scrollView:

```
<ScrollView 
    horizontal 
    style={{
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignContent:"center",
    marginTop: 20,// space between tabs and search bar
    height:30,
    }} 
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    >
    {categories.map((e)=>(
            <TouchableOpacity 
                key={e.id}
                onPress={()=>{
                    toggleBrands(e.id),
                    setLabelFilter(e.label)
                    }}
                selected={e.id === currentCategoryId}
                >
            <AppText style={[{fontWeight:"500"},label===e.label && {fontWeight:"700"}]}>{e.label}</AppText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    ))}
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl,
} from 'react-native';

const data = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];

const App = () => {
  const scrollY = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const diffClamp = Animated.diffClamp(scrollY, 0, 100);

  const translateY = diffClamp.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0, -60],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const marginTop = diffClamp.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0, -60],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const paddingTop = diffClamp.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [10, 110],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const opacity = diffClamp.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Text>{`Card ${item}`}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          zIndex: 100,
          paddingBottom: 10,
          transform: [{translateY}],
        }}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.searchBar, {opacity}]}>
          <Text>Search Bar</Text>
        </Animated.View>
        <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
          {data.map((num) => {
            return (
              <View key={num} style={styles.tab}>
                <Text>Tab</Text>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </Animated.View>
      <Animated.FlatList
        style={{marginTop, paddingTop}}
        // contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: 150}}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            tintColor="#fff"
            onRefresh={() => {
              console.warn('Refreshing');
            }}
            refreshing={false}
          />
        }
        bounces={true}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onScroll={(e) => {
          if (e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y > 0)
            scrollY.setValue(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  searchBar: {
    marginHorizontal: '5%',
    width: '90%',
    marginTop: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'lightgray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tab: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    width: 70,
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
  },
  card: {
    width: '90%',
    marginLeft: '5%',
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225761/discussion-on-answer-by-j-doe-react-native-trying-to-hide-search-bar-on-scroll).

Comment: Hi, hope you are doing good. Have you used socket.io before in react native?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with sockets.